# How to set up posts per page on WP

Tags: shortcode, pagination

I add this code on my website

```
[display-posts image_size="thumbnail" wrapper="div" 
    wrapper_class="display-posts-listing grid" meta_key="_thumbnail_id" 
    display-post category="<code>αρχείο-εκδηλώσεων</code>" posts_per_page="20" 
    display-posts include_excerpt="true" excerpt_length="15" 
    excerpt_more="Διαβάστε Περισσότερα" excerpt_more_link="true" ]
```

is it possible to put etc 20 posts and then the 21st post will be added on a second page ?

Comment: Since this shortcode comes from a third-party plugin you would need to contact the plugin author to determine whether this is possible.

Comment: Otherwise I can do this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the shortcode above but in regular WordPress, you can control the number of posts on your blog page under *Settings > Reading*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i know that but i want to add when on the first page that is maxed like 20 posts anyone can press like N.2 to go to the second page that will be olders posts like this
[image]